# Web IDE tool

Tags: javascript, html, ide

Does anyone know if it exists a Web IDE allowing to develop web application directly from a web application?
The W3School website allows to write small piece of code in HTML or javascript but is there another solution more project oriented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CodeRun**

http://www.coderun.com/

---

**Bespin from Mozilla Labs**

http://labs.mozilla.com/projects/bespin/

> Bespin is a Mozilla Labs experiment
>   that proposes an open, extensible
>   web-based framework for code editing
>   that aims to increase developer
>   productivity, enable compelling user
>   experiences, and promote the use of
>   open standards.

Comment: Bespin looks like a great tool but I think we still need to wait a little bit before this tool is fully operational!

Answer (score 2):

[Web2py](http://www.web2py.com) is a python web-app framework where you can develop applications directly from within the browser

Answer (score 1):

[clicpilot builder](http://www.clicpilot.com) is an online dev tool you can use to build WebApp just in browser. And it can generate NodeJS/JSP code and JQuery/Bootstrap Front-End code for you. it also support testing.

Answer (score 0):

http://htmledit.squarefree.com/

Well, it is easy to build an HTML editor. Here is my quick sample on phpe:

```
<form method="post">
<textarea id="editor" name="editor" style="width:100%;height:200px;"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" />
</form>
<hr />
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST["btnSubmit"])) {
        echo $_REQUEST["editor"];
    }
?>
```

Well, beware of attacks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget good old [Zope](http://www.zope.org/WhatIsZope), providing *through-the-web development* for many years
(Parts of Zope have been open source as far back as 1996, with the whole application server open source since 1998).

> What is Zope?
>
> Zope is an open source web application server primarily written in the Python programming language. It features a transactional object database which can store not only content and custom data, but also dynamic HTML templates, scripts, a search engine, and relational database (RDBMS) connections and code. **It features a strong through-the-web development model, allowing you to update your web site from anywhere in the world**. To allow for this, Zope also features a tightly integrated security model. Built around the concept of "safe delegation of control", Zope's security architecture also allows you to turn control over parts of a web site to other organizations or individuals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Koding](http://koding.com?c=ideh). It has all the stuff you need if you're a beginner and above all this you can collaborate with others and share your code.